# POJO dataset nested rendering

Tags: birt

My POJO Datasource basically contains following structure.
// **Company.java**

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 3130918429913376956L;
 private String name;
 private String address; 
 private String contactPerson;
 private String mobile; 
 private String fax; 
 private String bankDetails;
 private String email;
 private List<Employee> emps;
 //getter and setter.
  }
```

// **Employee.java**

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4473328670062370497L;
private String name;
private int age;
private String designation;
//getter and setter
}
```

My scenario is like following

1. One PDF report may have more that one Company (ie List< Company >)
2. In case of more than one Company, it should start at new page.
3. If Employee list goes to next page then it should repeat Header on the next page.

Layout -
[image]
[Layout xml source](https://pastebin.com/6PUhCNwh)
Output Page 1

[image]
Page 2
[image]

There are two issues with this design

1. `Employee Name` header is getting repeated for every employee.
2. Company Header (`Comp Name -> Company A` ) should be rendered only once.

Can anyone suggest me correct approach ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Move the 'company name' to the Header row and set the header property to not repeating on new pages. Move the 'Employee name' out of the grouping with 'Employee', so up to the level where 'company name' is now.

I think you know everything to solve this, you just have to fiddle with the groupings a bit.